# react-native android: safety about loading screens based on roles

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, security

Is there any harm to create a single react-native app and render screens according to the roles of the user?

Since every user will have access to the all of code.
A hacker could maybe track down the code, and get access to the manager code and do things to it.

```
import React from 'react';

export function App() {
  const user = useUser();

  if (user.role === 'admin') {
    return <Admin />;
  }

  if (user.role === 'customer') {
    return <Customer />;
  }

  if (user.role === 'super-admin') {
    return <SuperAdmin />;
  }

  return <General />;
}
```

Comment: I think that if the security is well managed on the API side, it cannot be hacked. Even if, let's suppose, a hacked customer user could navigate to the admin screen, at the first API call that would need an authorisation token, it will fail and he wouldn't be able to see any data or do anything

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: @dianaqqq as per my knowledge the code is minified, right? Is there any way to unminify the code?

Comment: Since the js code is not encrypted, there are ways to get to it and this is also a reason why we shouldn't store any sensitive data (like secret keys for example) on the mobile side. The main security part should be handled by the API